# DRAWER component of @material-ui/core does not appear when "open" prop is set to "true"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, babeljs, material-ui, jsx

Request: Please help me figure out how to get the drawer component to open when the variant prop is "temporary".

Material-UI package: @material-ui/core

I implemented Material UI's drawer component within my own custom Nav component. I cannot get the drawer to appear when I leave the variant prop as the default "temporary". I can clearly see (in my Chrome React plugin) that the "open" prop does get toggled to "true" but the drawer still does not appear. When I change the variant to "persistent" the drawer does in fact appear, but I much prefer using variant "temporary" because of its default behavior of closing when the user clicks anywhere on the screen.

Here is my code:

```js
import React, {Component} from 'react'
import AppBar from '@material-ui/core/AppBar';
import {Toolbar, Button} from "@material-ui/core"
import MenuIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Menu'
import IconButton from "@material-ui/core/es/IconButton/IconButton";
import Typography from "@material-ui/core/es/Typography/Typography";
import MenuItem from "@material-ui/core/es/MenuItem/MenuItem";
import Drawer from "@material-ui/core/es/Drawer/Drawer";
import ListItemText from "@material-ui/core/es/ListItemText/ListItemText";

class Nav extends Component {
 constructor() {
  super()
  this.state = {drawer: false}

  this.toggleDrawer = this.toggleDrawer.bind(this)
 }

 toggleDrawer(open) {
  debugger
  this.setState({
   drawer: open
  })
 }

 render() {
  const drawerMenu = (
   <div>
    <MenuItem><ListItemText primary="Home"></ListItemText></MenuItem>
    <MenuItem><ListItemText primary="Stock Points"></ListItemText></MenuItem>
    <MenuItem><ListItemText primary="Product Manager"></ListItemText></MenuItem>
   </div>
  )
  return (
   <div>
    <AppBar position="static">
     <Toolbar>
      <IconButton onClick={() => this.toggleDrawer(true)} color="inherit" aria-label="Menu">
       <MenuIcon />
      </IconButton>
      <Typography variant="title" color="inherit">
       {this.props.title}
      </Typography>
      <Button color="inherit">New Product</Button>
     </Toolbar>
    </AppBar>
    <Drawer open={this.state.drawer} onClose={() => this.toggleDrawer(false)} variant="temporary" keepMounted={true}>
     <div tabIndex={0} role="button" onClick={() => this.toggleDrawer(false)} onKeyDown={() => this.toggleDrawer(false)}>
      {drawerMenu}
     </div>
    </Drawer>
   </div>
  )
 }
}

export default Nav
```

Comment: I tested your code in codeSandbox... it seems to be working fine. The `Drawer` is hidden by default, and opens/closes when the menu button is clicked. Here is the [code sandbox demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/wkyzz8n35k?hidenavigation=1&module=%2Fsrc%2FDemo.js)

Comment: Thanks for confirming that it was not a syntax error. I did verify that it works in your codeSandbox. It must be my environment. I should probably verify the prereqs of material-ui v1+

Comment: Did you get this sorted out?

Comment: I ended up reverting back to v0 of material-ui. I had a good chunk of my project done in v0. I was just being ambitious with v1, but ended up running into too many barriers that were really slowing me down. Thanks again Luke.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've just had this issue now. Had the same problem with the code working on CodeSandbox but not in my browser. What helped me was updating Material-ui and React versions in package.json. Hope this helps!

Comment: Glad to hear that you were able to duplicate the issue. I have not tested it again, but I am almost certain this would fix my issue. Hope this helps someone else. Thanks.